# Basic Questions for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am currently studying the AngularJS technology and I have a  question.

I created an HTML (copied from the CodeProject site where I am studying this technology) which basically displays details of a book (ISBN, Price, etc.). You may refer to the snippet below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                            <td>{{item.ISBN}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <span ng-hide="editMode">{{item.Name}}</span>
                                <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="item.Name" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span ng-hide="editMode">{{item.Price}}</span>
                                <input type="number" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="item.Price" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span ng-hide="editMode">{{item.Quantity}}</span>
                                <input type="number" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="item.Quantity" />
                            </td>
                            <td>{{(item.Quantity) * (item.Price)}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <span><button type="submit" ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="editMode = true;editItem(item)">Edit</button></span>
                                <span><button type="submit" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="editMode = false">Save</button></span>
                                <span><input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="removeItem($index)"/></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

The controller name is Bookstore and below is the snippet:

```
app.controller("Bookstore", function($scope)
{
    $scope.items = [
        { ISBN: "5674789", Name: "ASP.NET MVC", Price: 560, Quantity: 20 },
        { ISBN: "4352134", Name: "AngularJS", Price: 450, Quantity: 25 },
        { ISBN: "2460932", Name: "Javascript", Price: 180, Quantity: 15 }
    ];
}

$scope.removeItem = function (index) {
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

QUESTION
1. What I am particularly confused about is the **$index** parameter in the html. Is this a built-in attribute of AngularJS which returns the index of the  wherein it's located? The reason I am asking this is because this was never initialized in the .js file so I am confused how the computer understands that $index is the position of the selected item.

I'm sorry if my question seem a bit confusing.

Comment: It is a variable angular exposes on the Ng repeat's scope. (each iteration has its own scope). It contains the current index in the bound array.  if you look up ng-repeat docs it'll be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `$index` is built-in parameter of `ng-repeat`. ng-repeat directive of angularJS automatically knows the index of the array it is iterating.

You can understand it better by comparing it with a `forEach` loop which knows the value of `index` as it iterates over the array.

For further clarification you can go through the documentation here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

You can also go through this nice blog post here to understand it better:
http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/05/13/understanding-angularjs-directives-part1-ng-repeat-and-compile/

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each item.

Within that child scope it creates properties such as `$index` internally

For full list of those scope properties see table at top of [`ng-repeat docs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0):

**$index** variable is dynamically created by angular's ng-repeat directive. It is similar to the index used by an array to store some data.

More on it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at that tutorial.